# Cannot create a cookie named refreshToken

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a problem, that I cannot create a new cookie with the name 'refreshToken' on local website. I am trying to set cookie from server and it isn't saved. I have then tried to manually creating it in chrome devtools, but it just disappears instantly: http://g.recordit.co/jSAWpWVWHX.gif

I can set it on deployed website. What could be the reason for that?

EDIT: The browser is chrome, tried on safari just now, everything was fine.

Comment: let's assume this is a chrome reserved word then, just use another name for your cookie..

Comment: It works on other pages, even on other deployment of the same webapp, only not on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings->Content settings->Cookies-> be sure is checked "Allow sites to save and read cookies"

Comment: It is selected.